# Не работают пуши Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push-уведомления

Что я только не делал - пуши просто не приходят, в лог ничего не выводится по поводу этого. Как пофиксить? Подскажите пожалуйста, ума не приложу.

П.с. везде вместо `startService` использую
`ContextCompat.startForegroundService`

Код:

```
class MyFcmListenerService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
        sendRegistrationToServer(token)
        RegistrationIntentService.enqueueWork(this)
    }

    // сохраняется в SharedPreferences
    private fun sendRegistrationToServer(token: String) {
        UserDataSecure.edit(KblApp.instance.sensitiveSettings).setPushToken(token).apply()
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        showNotification(message = remoteMessage.data["id"]!!)
    }

    ...
}
```

//***************************************************

```
class RegistrationIntentService : JobIntentService() {
    override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
        val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        try {
            subscribeTopics()
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e)
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply()
        }

        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        val registrationComplete = Intent(REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete)
    }

    private fun subscribeTopics() {
        for (topic in TOPICS) {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topic)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val JOB_ID = 42

        fun enqueueWork(context: Context) {
            val intent = Intent(context, RegistrationIntentService::class.java)
            enqueueWork(context, RegistrationIntentService::class.java, JOB_ID, intent)
        }

        private const val SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER = "sentTokenToServer"
        private const val REGISTRATION_COMPLETE = "registrationComplete"
        private const val TAG = "RegIntentService"
        private val TOPICS = arrayOf("global")
    }
}
```

//***************************************************

Manifest

```
<service
    android:name=".firebase.MyFcmListenerService"
    android:stopWithTask="false"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name=".firebase.RegistrationIntentService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">
</service>
```

//***************************************************

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

...

dependencies {
    ...

    /** Firebase */
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.4"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.5"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.4"
    implementation "com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2"

    ...
}
```

//***************************************************

Лог

```
W/FA-SVC: Interrupted in onRunTask while uploading
W/FA: Failed to retrieve Firebase Instance Id
W/FA: Failed to retrieve Firebase Instance Id
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to start service while in background: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT pkg=me.gira.widget.countdown cmp=me.gira.widget.countdown/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{b3e03e9 u0a170 RCVR idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
```

Comment: Попробуйте в логи вывести что приходит в `onNewToken` - если таки токен - то ваш вопрос о запуске сервиса из сервиса на OS>=8. Если же там `null` - то надо смотреть стоят ли на телефоне гугловые сервисы и не требуется ли им обновления. Возможно у вас эмулятор без них - тогда пуши работать не будут. В любом случае вам придётся потом решить проблему с запуском сервиса - но, желательно, в отдельном вопросе)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  `onNewToken` не срабатывает вообще (поставил лог туда). На телефоне (google pixel) все самые последние апдейты. Работаю не на эмуляторе, а на реальном девайсе.

Comment: Хм... Странно. У меня только 2 предположения, которые вряд ли помогут - перенести `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` в конец файла, как советуют в документации и опустить `firebase-core` до версии `16.0.4`, т.к. ваша версия у меня на днях сломала проект напрочь.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб понизил версию, теперь падает с ошибкой https://gist.github.com/indrih17/b1307620182475180b62a7452bb7fef9

Comment: Попробуйте и остальные либы понизить до `16.0.4`. Те, которые сейчас `16.0.5`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогло. Последняя ошибка, которая указана выше в логах, до сих пор возникает.

Comment: Других идей у меня нет( Ваш код выглядит идентично тому что тут описано и оно там работает: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48166636/3212712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось таким:

1) Tools -> Firebase -> Cloud Messaging -> Setup Firebase Cloud Messaging -> Connect to Firebase

2) Вместо `startService()` и `startForegroundService()` нужно использовать `enqueueWork()`

3) **(опционально)** Заменить все `IntentService` и `Service` на `JobIntentService`

4) **(опционально)** Для `IntentService` и `Service` перенести реализацию из `onStartCommand()` в `onHandleWork()`